# Why does the ZAxis not move when I autohome when using the BTT as a probe and the SKR e3V3 image?

Tags: marlin, bltouch, bigtreetech

I have a printer with a v3.1 BLTouch and a BTT SKR mini E3 V3 and I can't get the BLTouch to work as a probe while homing. I have tried both of the images provided [here](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/tree/master/firmware/V3.0/Marlin) and both cause the BLTouch to deploy properly but when I autohome and it gets to Z the BLtouch deploys (turns white) but the z axis doesn't move.

I found [this thread](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/issues/602) which provides an image that does work but not much about how he got it to work and there are some tweaks I would like to make. So no matter what I try when I try to build the image myself the ZProbe seems to not work. This experience seems to mirror others in the thread.

My Current configuration I am building [is available here](https://github.com/jrgleason/Marlin/tree/BTT_SKR_E3_V3_BLTOUCH)

Does anyone know what other settings may be required to get a BLTouch as a ZMin Probe working with the newest version?

Also quick side question the docs say that the 3.0.1 build [does not support BLTouch](https://github.com/bigtreetech/BIGTREETECH-SKR-mini-E3/tree/master/firmware/V3.0.1/Marlin), does anyone know why?

Comment: According to your last GitHub commit you seem to got it working, please consider to post an answer and accept the answer after 48 hours for other to learn from this exercise. Maybe add in the question by [edit] how your Z-probe is connected, I suspect you are not using the Z-min endstop. It could be that the precompiled bin files expect the Z-probe not to be connected to the dedicated probe header?

Comment: Will do let me get things kinda of tidied up and I will put something together.

Comment: Basically I think that was the answer mixed with when I changed them and reflashed the eprom wasn't getting reset (which I just assumed it would). So things should have changed but didn't see it because it was still set to the old one.

Comment: That would be excellent! When cleaning up, look at the v3.0.1 version in the first line, it appears to be linked to the BLTouch but shouldn't it be v3.1?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry finally getting back to answering the question. If this happens and your BLTouch is plugged into the Z-Probe you should make your Configuration file look like this...

```
//#define Z_MIN_PROBE_USES_Z_MIN_ENDSTOP_PIN
...
#define USE_PROBE_FOR_Z_HOMING
...
#define Z_SAFE_HOMING
```

This will tell Marlin to use the Probe instead of the endstop pins. Also in my case it was important to remember the EEProm does not seem to get reset when flashing the BTT SKR e3 mini v3. I think this is why when I tried flashing the other image it still didn't work. It would be my advice, if you are still having issues, to try resetting the EEProm as well.